# How safe are swift collections when used with invalidated iterators / indices?

Tags: swift, collections, iterator, invalidation

I'm not seeing a lot of info in the swift stdlib reference.  For example, Dictionary says certain methods (like remove) will invalidate indices, but that's it.

For a language to call itself "safe", it needs a solution to the classic C++ footguns:

1. get pointer to element in a vector, then add more elements (pointer is now invalidated), now use pointer, crash
2. start iterating through a collection.  while iterating, remove some elements (either before or after the current iterator position).  continue iterating, crash.

(edit: in c++, you're *lucky* to crash - worse case is memory corruption)

I believe 1 is solved by swift because if a collection stores classes, taking a reference (e.g. strong pointer) to an element will increase the refcount.  However, I don't know the answer for 2.

It would be super useful if there was a comparison of footguns in c++ that are/are not solved by swift.

EDIT, due to Robs answer:

It does appear that there's some undocumented snapshot-like behavior going on
with Dictionary and/or for loops.  The iteration creates a snapshot / hidden
copy of it when it starts.

Which gives me both a big "WAT" and "cool, that's sort of safe, I guess", and "how expensive is this copy?".

I don't see this documented either in Generator or in for-loop.

The below code prints two logical snapshots of the dictionary.  The first
snapshot is `userInfo` as it was at the start of the iteration loop, and does
not reflect any modifications made during the loop.

```
var userInfo: [String: String] = [
    "first_name" : "Andrei",
    "last_name" : "Puni",
    "job_title" : "Mad scientist"
]

userInfo["added_one"] = "1"  // can modify because it's var

print("first snapshot:")
var hijacked = false
for (key, value) in userInfo {
    if !hijacked {
        userInfo["added_two"] = "2"  // doesn't error     
        userInfo.removeValueForKey("first_name")  // doesn't error
        hijacked = true
    }
    print("- \(key): \(value)")
}

userInfo["added_three"] = "3" // modify again

print("final snapshot:")
for (key, value) in userInfo {
    print("- \(key): \(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you say, #1 is not an issue. You do not have a pointer to the object in Swift. You either have its value or a reference to it. If you have its value, then it's a copy. If you have a reference, then it's protected. So there's no issue here.

But let's consider the second and experiment, be surprised, and then stop being surprised.

```
var xs = [1,2,3,4]

for x in xs { // (1)
    if x == 2 {
        xs.removeAll() // (2)
    }
    print(x) // Prints "1\n2\n3\n\4\n"
}

xs // [] (3)
```

Wait, how does it print all the values when we blow away the values at (2). We are very surprised now.

But we shouldn't be. Swift arrays are *values*. The `xs` at (1) is a value. Nothing can ever change it. It's not "a pointer to memory that includes an array structure that contains 4 elements." It's the *value* `[1,2,3,4]`. At (2), we don't "remove all elements from the thing `xs` pointed to." We take the thing xs *is*, create an array that results if you remove all the elements (that would be `[]` in all cases), and then assign that new array to `xs`. Nothing bad happens.

So what does the documentation mean by "invalidates all indices?" It means exactly that. If we generated indices, they're no good anymore. Let's see:

```
var xs = [1,2,3,4]

for i in xs.indices {
    if i == 2 {
        xs.removeAll()
    }
    print(xs[i]) // Prints "1\n2\n" and then CRASH!!!
}
```

Once `xs.removeAll()` is called, there's no promise that the old result of `xs.indices` means anything anymore. You are not permitted to use those indices safely against the collection they came from.

"Invalidates indices" in Swift is not the same as C++'s "invalidates iterators." I'd call that pretty safe, except the fact that using collection indices is always a bit dangerous and so you should avoid indexing collections when you can help it; iterate them instead. Even if you need the indexes for some reason, use `enumerate` to get them without creating any of the danger of indexing.

(Side note, `dict["key"]` is not indexing into `dict`. Dictionaries are a little confusing because their key is not their index. Accessing dictionaries by their `DictionaryIndex` index is just as dangerous as accessing arrays by their `Int` index.)

Note also that the above doesn't apply to `NSArray`. If you modify `NSArray` while iterating it, you'll get a "mutated collection while iterating" error. I'm only discussing Swift data types.

---

EDIT: `for-in` is [very explicit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID428) in how it works:

> The generate() method is called on the collection expression to obtain a value of a generator type—that is, a type that conforms to the GeneratorType protocol. The program begins executing a loop by calling the next() method on the stream. If the value returned is not None, it is assigned to the item pattern, the program executes the statements, and then continues execution at the beginning of the loop. Otherwise, the program does not perform assignment or execute the statements, and it is finished executing the for-in statement.

The returned `Generator` is a `struct` and contains a collection value. You would not expect any changes to some other value to modify its behavior. Remember: `[1,2,3]` is no different than `4`. They're both values. When you assign them, they make copies. So when you create a Generator over a collection value, you're going to snapshot that value, just like if I created a Generator over the number 4. (This raises an interesting problem, because Generators aren't really values, and so really shouldn't be structs. They should be classes. Swift stdlib has been fixing that. See the new `AnyGenerator` for instance. But they still contain an array value, and you would never expect changes to some other array value to impact them.)

See also ["Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82) which goes into more detail on the importance of value types in Swift. Arrays are just structs.

Yes, that means there's logically copying. Swift has many optimizations to minimize actual copying when it's not needed. In your case, when you mutate the dictionary while it's being iterated, that will force a copy to happen. Mutation is cheap if you're the only consumer of a particular value's backing storage. But it's O(n) if you're not. (This is determined by the Swift builtin `isUniquelyReferenced()`.) Long story short: Swift Collections are Copy-on-Write, and simply passing an array does not cause real memory to be allocated or copied.

You don't get COW for free. Your own structs are *not* COW. It's something that Swift does in stdlib. (See Mike Ash's [great discussion](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html) of how you would recreate it.) Passing your own custom structs causes real copies to happen. That said, the majority of the memory in most structs is stored in collections, and those collections are COW, so the cost of copying structs is usually pretty small.

The book doesn't spend a lot of time drilling into value types in Swift (it explains it all; it just doesn't keep saying "hey, and this is what that implies"). On the other hand, it was the constant topic at WWDC. You may be interested particularly in [Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=414) which is all about this topic. I believe [Swift in Practice](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=411) also discussed it.

---

EDIT2:

@KarlP raises an interesting point in the comments below, and it's worth addressing. None of the value-safety promises we're discussing are related to `for-in`. They're based on `Array`. `for-in` makes no promises at all about what would happen if you mutated a collection while it is being iterated. That wouldn't even be meaningful. `for-in` doesn't "iterate over collections," it calls `next()` on `Generators`. So if your `Generator` becomes undefined if the collection is changed, then `for-in` will blow up because the `Generator` blew up.

That means that the following might be unsafe, depending on how strictly you read the spec:

```
func nukeFromOrbit<C: RangeReplaceableCollectionType>(var xs: C) {
    var hijack = true
    for x in xs {
        if hijack {
            xs.removeAll()
            hijack = false
        }
        print(x)
    }
}
```

And the compiler won't help you here. It'll work fine for all of the Swift collections. But if calling `next()` after mutation for *your* collection is undefined behavior, then this is undefined behavior.

My opinion is that it would be poor Swift to make a collection that allows its `Generator` to become undefined in this case. You could even argue that you've broken the `Generator` spec if you do (it offers no UB "out" unless the generator has been copied or has returned nil). So you could argue that the above code is totally within spec and your generator is broken. Those arguments tend to be a bit messy with a "spec" like Swift's which doesn't dive into all the corner cases.

Does this mean you can write unsafe code in Swift without getting a clear warning? Absolutely. But in the many cases that commonly cause real-world bugs, Swift's built-in behavior does the right thing. And in that, it is safer than some other options.

Comment: I ran the code, and the output looks as expected. `popFirst()` is not well-defined on a Dictionary (in that order is not defined), but it's certainly doing the right thing. And the output looks good, and the lack of errors is correct. Looks like you have the idea.

Comment: disregard the previous comment.  I have edited the post with the 'snapshot like' behavior, which I don't see documented anywhere.   If you can provide a more precise and official explanation for this, then I will upvote you.

Comment: So the actual reason is that the *generator* is a value type, not that Array or Dictionary are value types? Or perhaps that the concrete  generators (IndexingGenerator, DictionaryGenerator) are structs? I don't see that the SequenceType *protocol* enforces that `generate()` returns a struct. (I am just curious because I wondered about the same problem once: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8551).

Comment: The generator could also be implemented by having an unsafe pointer to your collection, could it not?

Comment: @martin I can't believe all the responses in that thread saying "it's a value type! dur!".  Yeah, value types are obviously copied WHEN WE SEE A COPY.  There's no obvious "copying" in a for-in loop construct.

Comment: Thanks for the mike ash link.  I do see that only a mutating function should cause the copying to be triggered.  (e.g. just making a generator should not).  I will upvote your answer.  However, I still find the official apple reference so atrociously underspeced I can't / won't "accept" it yet.  (Nothing against you)

Comment: Value types are about how their intended to behave, not the consequence of specs (Swift has no spec). You could create collections that violate this behavior and are unsafe. You get the same behavior with reference type Generators. You could break the behavior by directly referencing the buffer instead of the array. Swift is not a spec-driven language any more than ObjC is. Lots of things exist in Cocoa because "that's how Apple feels they should work." And in this case, the fact that for-in snapshots its collection is because it's one of the collections Apple wants to copy in this case.

Comment: Cocoa dev has *always* been a matter of divining Apple's intent and thereby inferring how it's likely implemented. There has never been an independent spec, so while it's possible to say "Apple is inconsistent here" it has always been very difficult to say "Apple is violating spec here." Like Perl, Swift is what Swift does much more than it is what a very strict document says. People can hate that, but it's always been the case in Cocoa. It's just not a very tightly speced world.

Comment: (I'm of course conflating Swift with its stdlib here. Array's value behavior is totally a consequence of its implementation, which is arguably not "Swift." For-in, as you say, promises no such behaviors. But Array does because it's a value.)

Comment: By spec (the reference manual) mutating something in the middle of for-in is not strictly defined. So the full answer is "never do that, UB." But it doesn't seem a particularly useful answer.

Comment: Updated answer with more exploration of this. It's a good question, it just isn't about `for-in`. It's about what it means to be a Generator and what's required of you and what isn't required of you. @MartinR, I think this gets to your question too. In-loop mutation is well protected (even if there is no numbered paragraph that states it) for stdlib collections. It is not well protected or even well defined for arbitrary collections you may create on your own unless you define it yourself.

Comment: I accepted your answer since you admitted it was undefined currently :-)  FWIW I think the swift semantics are ok but initially jarring because it's different than say C# IEnumerable (which makes a runtime error to continue iterating a modified collection).  It seems that swift collections are practically as safe as Rust (threads notwithstanding), while being much easier to use.