# When to use enumerate for arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, mutable

I noticed strange things happen when you try to remove or mutate array items in a loop. However, when doing it while calling `enumerate()` on the array, it works as expected. What is the concept behind it and when should we use `enumerate()`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you provide a sample of your issue with a loop vs enumerate and the expected and actual behavior?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32425212/1187415.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question from the title, you use `enumerate()` when you need value's index in addition to the value itself:

> If you need the integer index of each item as well as its value, use the `enumerate()` method to iterate over the array instead.
>
> ```
> for (index, value) in shoppingList.enumerate() {
>     print("Item \(index + 1): \(value)")
> }
> ```

`enumerate()` provides a safe pattern for modifying array elements while iterating over them:

```
for (index, (var value)) in shoppingList.enumerate() {
    if value == "something" {
        shoppingList[index] = "something-else"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"while generate(), the method used in the regular loop, does not."*? – A "regular" loop is safe as well: `for elem in array { array.removeAll() }` runs without problems.

Comment: @MartinR That's nice to know. I guess I shouldn't be commenting on the reason anyway, because too many parts could be in play (is element a class or a struct, is loop variable a `var`, is the array itself changed, or only its elements, and so on). The idea was, of course, to demonstrate the cute trick, which my comment in the middle did not help a slightest bit. Thanks!